# JQuery UI Dialog Problems (buttons & autoopen not working)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I inherited the source for site which already has JQuery & JQueryUI included.

jquery-1.3.2.min.js

1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js

I have created a dialog:

```
        $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: true, 
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        width: 400,
        height: 175,
        modal: true
    });
```

---

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Confirm Company Deletion">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you wish to remove this company from the system?<br><br>Whilst the company will no longer be visible after deletion its records will remain within the database and therefore may be recoverable in the future. If this is ever required please contact the system administrator.</p>
</div>
```

The first problem I am having is the dialog does not auto open. The second problem is that the buttons are not showing. However the width, height and model settings are applied.

If I call javascript:$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open'); The dialogue opens (without the buttons - the button elements aren't even created) and have spent hours trying to figure this out already. I need some help diagnosing this issue because I have tried changing the order in which the script, library & theme is loaded but it has made no difference. I am debugging with Chrome but there are no errors, so any suggestions for property's to look at, any debugging tips will be Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, if you set auto open to true, then you don't need to do a dialog('open'), just a dialog().  Also, obvious point, but maybe you could upgrade to the latest jQuery releases and see if that sorts it?  I've also never invoked a jquery dialog from within an href with javascript:$('#...etc.  Perhaps try binding it to the element's onclick event and see if that helps?

Comment: @dartacus: Thanks it seemed to be a crappy version of Jquery (not the UI library) - Had some initial problems after the upgrade but all working now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're not calling this code at all.
The reason that your buttons don't appear when you call...

```
$('#dialog-modal').dialog('open');
```

...is because this is a completely separate invocation of the dialog handler, and it doesn't specify any buttons.

Answer (score 0):

conflict between version of jquery & jquery ui

edit: have to wait 2 days to accept own answer zzz